# How can I install multiple Zope instances as Windows services

Tags: windows, plone, zope

I am running multiple zope instances on a Windows server. At present I can only run the initial instance as a Windows service. This was installed as a full Plone install. The other two instances were created using buildout.cfg and are run through the console using a scheduled task. This is not a robust solution and is affecting performance of the sites. Any ideas how I can install multiple Zope instances as Windows services.

Comment: looks like none of the plone+windows experts read your question. as your question is not really plone/zope related you might tag it with windows and ask the windows experts how to set up  a service for your $BUILDOUT/bin/instance script

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

I have set up multiple versions of Plone (e.g. 3.x, 4.1, 4.3) on the same Windows machine using the Windows installer but each time installing to separate target directories.

In my case I would run only one Plone version at a time, so I didn't have to change which port number each Zope used. I just created .bat files that would start and just the Zope I wanted (and stop all the others) but you would also have to edit the port number used by each Zope so they could listen on different ports simultaneously. (I'm not sure how to do that).